# Android - correct way to highlight multiple image items in Grid/Listview

Tags: android, listview

I have a list view in my app with elements where an image covers pretty much all of the view. There was an article by google where they explain that selectors should be drawn on top of the item if the item's background is not visible or else you wont see the selection highlight. Can't find this article anymore.

The list view has been correctly configured with drawSelectorOnTop and a selector for various states. Each item on a list view is a RelativeLayout with a background selector for various states including *activated*. When selecting multiple items and marking them as checked, the items are correctly marked but since a big image covers almost all of the view, just a fraction of the background is shown in the highlighted color.

I fixed my problem by wrapping the relative layout into a frame layout and setting a foreground drawable to draw the highlights. It works, but I don't like adding the extra layout on my elements.

Ideally, the selector of the listview should be used to mark the items, but apparently not. I included all possible states on the list view selector but it never leaves the item highlighted.

My question is: is wrapping items in a framelayout the correct way of doing this or is there a better approach?